# Whats wrong with my faces?

Tags: faces

So I've been working on this model for class and right now I'm trying to clean up some faces. Well, for some reason a few of my faces look weird and I can't figure it out. Any answers will be very helpful also any explaination on the casue of this will be amazing.[image: The two images show the issue im having in farther detail, Check the sleeves.]

[image]

Comment: Select all the mesh and smooth it. Have you tried this?

Comment: Smooth the mesh (open up the *Tool Shelf* with **T**, then *Tools-Edit panel-Shading:Smooth*) as Fuboski suggested. You may also try to **recalculate normals** (select the whole mesh with **A** in *Edit Mode*, then press **Ctrl+N**).

Comment: Thank you very much guys for responding. I did what Paul Gonet said and it turned out reversing the normals completely solved the face issue. Thanks again guys